# How to find a basis for orthogonal complement, given the linear map?

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

Given a linear map  $\langle \cdot\,, \cdot \rangle:\, P_3(\mathbb{R}) \times P_3(\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by:
$$
⟨p,q⟩ = \int_{0}^{2} p(x) q(x) \, dx 
$$
for all $p,q \in P_3(\mathbb{R})$.

If $⟨\cdot\,,\cdot⟩$ is an inner product on $P_3(\mathbb{R})$, what is the basis for $\{ x, x^2 \}^\bot$?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

We say that two vectors are orthogonal when their inner product is zero.

Moreover, a vector is orthogonal to a vector space iff it is orthogonal to one of its basis.

At your case, take a polynomial $f\in\textbf{P}_{3}(\mathbb{R})$, apply the restrictions $\langle f,x\rangle = \langle f,x^{2}\rangle = 0$ and solve the corresponding system of linear equations.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: thanks for your answer! Am I suppose to take a random polynomial P3 and solve the system of equations? Also, what do I do with the fact that map is integral of product of 2 functions?